# django-celery warnings about settings.DEBUG

Tags: django, django-celery

I have some questions regarding running djcelery.

When I run

```
python manage.py celeryd --setting=settings
```

The workers seem to have started but the warnings concern me:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djcelery\loaders.py:86: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
```

Googled for this warning message but no one seems to care about it. Should I be concerned?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is what it says it is - a warning that `settings.DEBUG` should not be set for production deployments. If you're just using it for development, then it is not something to be concerned about. In general, this ought to apply whether you use django-celery or not.

I have not looked up the details, but as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806384/115845):

> When `DEBUG` is enabled Django appends every executed SQL statement to `django.db.connection.queries`, this will grow unbounded in a long running process environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually, I accidentally solved the problem today.

Comment: So it means that the problem is keep `DEBUG` with a `True` value?

Comment: @theSekyi just remove this env variable, setting it to False doesn't seem to work

Comment: Celery copied some code from the Django project to complain about setting settings.DEBUG to True, but when the upstream problem was fixed (in Django 1.8) they warning was never removed. It will be removed soon though.

Answer (score 1):

The officially recommended way to start celeryd for django-celery is:

```
python manage.py celeryd --setting=settings
```

Today, I forgot this and directly start celeryd by

```
python -m celery.bin.celeryd --config=settings
```

and viola, no warnings! And it works just fine! The Celery group really need to work on their docs. Although it seems comprehensive, some key pieces are missing to cover all the grounds imho.

Comment: Glad you found a solution you're happy with. IMHO, the warnings were never a problem, and what you've done is bypass django and all the checks that may come with it. It may work now, but since you've not used the recommended approach there's no guarantee that all is ok (now, or in future updates). Of course, since I'm not familiar with djcelery I may simply be speaking out I ignorance. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... Django stopped leaking memory in Django 1.8 https://github.com/django/django/commit/cfcca7ccce3dc527d16757ff6dc978e50c4a2e61

A fix for celery such that it won't complain anymore is underway.

Comment: I think for this using your comennting privilege would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @Yunnosch why is that? Seems to me that the passage of time has made it so that a new answer is correct. Why not provide it exactly as such?

Comment: Makes sense, so please turn it into an answer according to [answer], keeping in mind that linked content is not considered part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.8, Django no longer leaks memory when `DEBUG=True`.

See https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/7626. This pull request removed the out dated warning and will be included in the [Celery 5.3](https://github.com/celery/celery/milestone/36) release.