# Celery does not release memory

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

It looks like celery does not release memory after task finished. Every time a task finishes, there would be 5m-10m memory leak. So with thousands of tasks, soon it will use up all memory.

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user@localhost:5672/vhost'
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://user@localhost:5672/vhost'

CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'tasks.tasks',
)

CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
# CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600
# maximum time for a task to execute
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 600
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = "default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = "direct"
# CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 50
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 2
```

Might be same with issue, but it does not has an answer:
[RabbitMQ/Celery/Django Memory Leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302503/rabbitmq-celery-django-memory-leak)

I am not using django, and my packages are:

```
Chameleon==2.11
Fabric==1.6.0
Mako==0.8.0
MarkupSafe==0.15
MySQL-python==1.2.4
Paste==1.7.5.1
PasteDeploy==1.5.0
SQLAlchemy==0.8.1
WebOb==1.2.3
altgraph==0.10.2
amqp==1.0.11
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
billiard==2.7.3.28
biplist==0.5
celery==3.0.19
chaussette==0.9
distribute==0.6.34
flower==0.5.1
gevent==0.13.8
greenlet==0.4.1
kombu==2.5.10
macholib==1.5.1
objgraph==1.7.2
paramiko==1.10.1
pycrypto==2.6
pyes==0.20.0
pyramid==1.4.1
python-dateutil==2.1
redis==2.7.6
repoze.lru==0.6
requests==1.2.3
six==1.3.0
tornado==3.1
translationstring==1.1
urllib3==1.6
venusian==1.0a8
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.deprecation==4.0.2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

I just added a test task like, test_string is a big string, and it still has memory leak:

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def process_crash_xml(test_string, client_ip, request_timestamp):
    logger.info("%s %s" % (client_ip, request_timestamp))
    test = [test_string] * 5
```

Comment: are you using `virtualenv`? do you have the list of packages/versions you are using?

Comment: if you are using django make sure DEBUG = False

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was this config option that made my worker does not release memory.

```
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 600
```

refer to: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1427

Answer (score 11):

There are two settings which can help you mitigate growing memory consumption of celery workers:

- [Max tasks per child setting](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting)  (v2.0+):

> With this option you can configure the maximum number of tasks a worker can execute before it’s replaced by a new process. This is useful if you have memory leaks you have no control over for example from closed source C extensions.

- [Max memory per child setting](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#max-memory-per-child-setting) (v4.0+):

> With this option you can configure the maximum amount of resident memory a worker can execute before it’s replaced by a new process.
> This is useful if you have memory leaks you have no control over for example from closed source C extensions.

However, those options only work with the default pool (prefork).

For safe guarding against memory leaks for threads and gevent pools you can add an utility process called [memmon](https://superlance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memmon.html), which is part of the [superlance](https://superlance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension to supervisor.

Memmon can monitor all running worker processes and will restart them automatically when they exceed a predefined memory limit.

Here is an example configuration for your supervisor.conf:

```
[eventlistener:memmon]
command=/path/to/memmon -p worker=512MB
events=TICK_60
```

Answer (score 7):

When you start your worker just set the max-tasks-per-child option like this to restart worker processes after every task:

`celery -A app worker --loglevel=info --max-tasks-per-child=1`

Here's the documentation:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting

> With this option you can configure the maximum amount of resident memory a worker can execute before it’s replaced by a new process.
>
> This is useful if you have memory leaks you have no control over for example from closed source C extensions.
>
> The option can be set using the workers --max-memory-per-child argument or using the worker_max_memory_per_child setting.

Answer (score 2):

set [worker_max_tasks_per_child](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#max-tasks-per-child-setting) in your settings

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in celery which I think is fixed.

Please refer: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2927

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting [this issue](https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq/issues/15) in `librabbitmq`. Please check whether or not Celery is using `librabbitmq>=1.0.1`.

A simple fix to try is: `pip install librabbitmq>=1.0.1`.

Comment: I am not using librabbitmq. Celery requires "amqp>=1.0.11,<1.1.0" to run.