# CeleryBeat Process consumes all OS memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

We are using

```
django-celery==3.1.10
celery==3.1.20
python 2.7.13
```

We have written a CustomDataBaseScheduler to schedule task, which schedules the task perfectly on time. We are running CeleryBeat Process as init script, but celeryBeat consumes Full memory of the system i.e. 24GB in a day.

I tried to run pmap on celerybeat Process, but it shows [anon] has took the most memory.

Can someone please help to debug and fix this.

Comment: Did you look into any options of timeout or so, like `CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541452/celery-does-not-release-memory

Comment: Any chance you are running with debug = True on settings.py? It is known that this causes a memory leak on celery: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/smV5tw59Ia4

Comment: Migrate to http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: does your debug turned on?

Comment: This Parameter is for CELERY Workers.. Although have tried with .. 
########  Celery Settings
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=120  # 2 minutes
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="amqp"
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS=False
CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_EXPIRES=60
but invain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if you are on django 1.8 or above please use celery 4.0 and above. In that case you will not require django-celery. Also in that case follow this tutorial.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Coming to your problem it may be one of the following reasons:

1. Your workers are overloaded. Try using concurrency as mentioned [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency)
2. Check if  your django settings `DEBUG` is set to `True`. It can cause memory leakages and celery advises against it when you run it.
3. Check for memory leak fixes in the [history](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/index.html). To me it seemed the next version after yours, [3.1.21](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/changelog-3.1.html#version-3-1-21) to be precise has some memory leak fixes. Try upgrading to the latest 3.x version(only if you cannot use 4.x for any reason.)
4. If all else fails, try some monitoring tools to debug the scenario about what is happening. Some monitoring tools are mentioned [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html).

Comment: django is 1.7, so cannot use celery 4. 
debug is True in settings.py but we use init scripts to start celery where we have used INFO not debug.

Comment: I meant `debug` in django settings.py. When you run celery with django `DEBUG=True` in settings.py, you will get [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/d90caee6d91a0fcc91756329503a35bf8fef720a/celery/fixups/django.py#L202). Switch off debug and check if that works.

Comment: tried upgrading django-celery==3.2.1 but it requires upgrading of django>=1.8 and we have django==1.7
So upgraded django-celery==3.1.17 which is latest in 3.1. Also will try with debug=False.

Comment: That's great,  thanks to @rmad17, turning off debug  in django settings.py fixes the memory issue cause by celery beat..